# Web API request error in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I am trying to develop an mobile application using asp.net web api and xamarin forms. Getting errors like this

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request

I developed all the application Mobile, Web in a same solution. Then Created web api with individual login using visual studio 2017.
This is my source code for RegisterBinding model

**RegisterBinding.cs**

```
public class RegisterBindingModel
{
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Then i created viewmodel for xamarin binding
**RegisterViewModel.cs**

```
    class RegisterViewModel
    {
    ApiServices _apiserv = new ApiServices(); 
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public ICommand RegisterCommand {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async() =>
            {
                var isSucess = await _apiserv.RegisterAsync(Email, Password, ConfirmPassword);
                if (isSucess)
                {
                    Message = "Sucessfully Registered!";
                }
                else
                {
                    Message = "Try again";
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Also i create apiservice to connect mobile app and web api service

**ApiService.cs**

```
public async Task<bool> RegisterAsync(string email, string password, string confirmPassword)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();

                var model = new RegisterBindingModel
                {
                    Email = email,
                    Password = password,
                    ConfirmPassword = confirmPassword
                };

                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

                HttpContent _content = new StringContent(json);

                _content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");


                var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:54996/api/Account/Register", _content);
                return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;

            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }


        }
```

Finally my view for xamarin xaml is

RegisterPage.cs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CIDSCONMOB.Views.RegisterPage"
            xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CIDSCONMOB.ViewModels">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:RegisterViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Entry Text="{Binding Email}"
               Placeholder="Email"/>
        <Entry Text="{Binding Password}"
               Placeholder="Password"
               IsPassword="True"/>
        <Entry Text="{Binding ConfirmPassword}"
               Placeholder="Confirm Password"
               IsPassword="True"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding RegisterCommand}"
                 Text="Sign Up"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Message}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

This is the Error when i click the register button

[HTTP Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdeeL.png)

As i am very new to xamarin development please help me to find solution for this issue

Comment: a. don't use localhost, b. look at the InnerException to get the actual root cause

Comment: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'. after changing localhost to ipaddress

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely in the address you're using `http://localhost:54996/api/Account/Register`. When running on a simulator or actual device, think of it as an external machine. Thus, `localhost` will point to that simulator/device.

Retrieve the address of the machine where your server application is running on, make sure it is connected to the same network as your simulator/device, enter that as an address and try again.

The address will most likely start with `192.168.x.x` or `10.x.x.x`.

Also, there is probably more detail in the `InnerException`, better check that first.

Comment: But how this guys gets output https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0v4srA4NhA and how to check innerexception

Comment: Because he is running the UWP app which runs on the same device as his server application

Comment: Ok can i use the ipaddress of my own system using ipconfig command

Comment: That should be the one. And make sure the connection is allow through your firewall.

Comment: Now its throwing this exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'. and system ip address is 192.168.0.104 and mobile ip is 192.168.232.2

Comment: On what line does this happen?

Comment: At the line of await client.postAsync()  it moves to the catch and throws exception

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see any reason for that to happen